# How do I access the custom class by knowing a variable from that class?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I created a custom class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Obstacle {
    public GameObject gameObj;
    public Color color;

    public GameObject starExplosion;
    public GameObject regular_Trail;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool firstCollistion = true;

    public static Vector3 SpawnLocation()
    {
        int positionQuadran = Random.Range(1, 3);
        switch (positionQuadran)
        {
            //spawn above the player
            case 1:
                 return new Vector3(Random.Range(1.5f, -1.5f),
                                                      Random.Range(4f - SpawnStars.closerToPlayer, 4.5f),
                                                      Random.Range(1, -3.2f));
            //spawn benith the player
            case 2:
                return new Vector3(Random.Range(1.5f, -1.5f),
                                                      Random.Range(-0.5f, SpawnStars.closerToPlayer),
                                                      Random.Range(1f, -3.2f));
        }
        return Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Now, as you can see in this class there is a variable `public GameObject gameObj;` Now in another script I need to acces the instance of the `Obstacle` class that this `gameObj` instance is in. And I am trying to do that like this:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    collision.collider. //what do I do next?
}
```

For a few reasons I don't want to make the `Obstacle` class inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. Since I can't access this class from another `GameObject` that would be in the scene how do I access it by only knowing the `gameObj` variable?

Update I will add the script that I use to generate the Obstacle Class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class SpawnStars : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private List<Obstacle> obstacles;
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<Obstacle> normalStarsPool = new List<Obstacle>();

    [SerializeField]
    private List<Obstacle> otherObstacles;
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<Obstacle> otherObstaclesPool;

    [SerializeField]
    private int spawnNumber = 2;

    private Obstacle nextObstacleToSpawn;
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject panel;
    public static bool spawnNow = true;
    public static bool first_find_star = true;

    public static float starSpeed;
    /* this variables will make the stars to spawn closer and closer to the player as 
    the score  is progresing*/
    public static float closerToPlayer;
    private float spawnPositionZ;

    private void Start()
    {
        first_find_star = true;
        spawnNow = true;

        GeneratePrefabs(spawnNumber, obstacles, normalStarsPool);
        StartCoroutine(ShuffleList(normalStarsPool));

        GeneratePrefabs(2, otherObstacles, otherObstaclesPool);
        StartCoroutine(ShuffleList(otherObstaclesPool));
    }
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (spawnNow)
        {
            spawnNow = false;
            if (first_find_star)
            {
                nextObstacleToSpawn = FindStar(normalStarsPool);
                first_find_star = false;
            }
            //spawn the current star
            int randomNumber = Random.Range(0, 100);
            if(randomNumber >= 20){
                nextObstacleToSpawn = FindStar(normalStarsPool);
            }
            else{
                Debug.Log("corrupt star");
                nextObstacleToSpawn = FindStar(otherObstacles);
            }
            SpawnStar(nextObstacleToSpawn);

        }
    }
    void GeneratePrefabs(int how_many, List<Obstacle> prefabList, List<Obstacle> poolList)
    {
        foreach (Obstacle prefab in prefabList)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= how_many; i++)
            {
                Obstacle go = new Obstacle
                {
                    gameObj = Instantiate(prefab.gameObj)
                };
                go.regular_Trail = go.gameObj.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
                go.starExplosion = go.gameObj.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
                go.color = prefab.color;
                go.gameObj.SetActive(false);

                //setap all the colors for the obstacle
                ParticleSystem ps = go.starExplosion.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
                ParticleSystem.MainModule psmain = ps.main;
                psmain.startColor = go.color;

                //setup the collor of a partycle system
                ps = go.starExplosion.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
                psmain = ps.main;
                psmain.startColor = go.color;

                psmain.startColor = go.color;

                go.gameObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = go.color;
                poolList.Add(go);
            }
        }
    }
    Obstacle FindStar(List<Obstacle> poolList)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, poolList.Count);
            if (!poolList[randomIndex].gameObj.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                Color color = poolList[randomIndex].color;
                color.a = 0.5f;
                panel.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
                return poolList[randomIndex];
            }
            else randomIndex = Random.Range(0, poolList.Count);
        }
    }
        void SpawnStar(Obstacle star)
    {
        star.firstCollistion = false;
        star.starExplosion.SetActive(false);
        star.regular_Trail.SetActive(true);
        star.gameObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        ScaleDifficulty();
        star.gameObj.transform.position = Obstacle.SpawnLocation();
        star.gameObj.SetActive(true);
    }

    //Shuffle a list every 4 seconds, don't pus this in an update or something cuz it's a coroutine
    IEnumerator ShuffleList(List<Obstacle> list_to_Shuffle)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
            for (int i = 0; i < list_to_Shuffle.Count; i++)
            {
                Obstacle temp = list_to_Shuffle[i];
                int randomIndex = Random.Range(i, list_to_Shuffle.Count);
                list_to_Shuffle[i] = list_to_Shuffle[randomIndex];
                list_to_Shuffle[randomIndex] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //this will scale the difficulty as the score get's higher and higher
    public void ScaleDifficulty()
    {
        if (Menu.score < 60)
        {
            //the speed of the star as the score goes up
            starSpeed = ((float)Menu.score / 30) + 1f;
            //how close relative to the player will the stars spawn in the x and y axis?
            closerToPlayer += Menu.score / 60;
           // Debug.Log(starSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see i generated the Obstacle objects in this method:

```
void GeneratePrefabs(int how_many, List<Obstacle> prefabList, List<Obstacle> poolList)
{
    foreach (Obstacle prefab in prefabList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= how_many; i++)
        {
            Obstacle go = new Obstacle
            {
                gameObj = Instantiate(prefab.gameObj)
            };
            go.regular_Trail = go.gameObj.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
            go.starExplosion = go.gameObj.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            go.color = prefab.color;
            go.gameObj.SetActive(false);

            //setap all the colors for the obstacle
            ParticleSystem ps = go.starExplosion.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
            ParticleSystem.MainModule psmain = ps.main;
            psmain.startColor = go.color;

            //setup the collor of a partycle system
            ps = go.starExplosion.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
            psmain = ps.main;
            psmain.startColor = go.color;

            psmain.startColor = go.color;

            go.gameObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = go.color;
            poolList.Add(go);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you create the instance of the `Obstacle` class?

Comment: I updated the question at your request :)

Comment: use the gameobjects `GetComponent<T>()` method

Comment: @yes He can't because `Obstacle` does not inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: @Programmer oops, right, my bad :S why not make it one then @Noobie? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't. Not the way you've got things set up. If you need to access that object globally, you'll need to keep track of it globally. Unity provides a way to do that (essentially the [Service Locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)), but you've said you don't want to use it. So you're going to have to build your own.

Assuming you've got a collection of your `Obstacle` objects, e.g. `IList<Obstacle> obstacles` you could get it by `obstacles.Where(o => o.gameObj == myLocalGameObjReference)`. A better solution, assuming you have this script attached 1:1 for each `Obstacle` would be to simple inject the `Obstacle` into the script. Look at a dependency injection (DI) framework like [Zenject](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject) to assist with configuring and managing your dependencies. Another alternative is the [singleton pattern](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton). Personally, I'd opt for DI over singleton. The singleton seems easier at first, but you'll quickly run into trouble with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Now in another script I need to acces the instance of the Obstacle class that this gameObj instance is in.

Given an instance of an `Obstacle` class, how can you even know that it is referenced by an instance of `GameObject` at all? Or how can you know that it's referenced by *only one* `GameObject?`

Unless there's a two-way reference - the `GameObject` has a reference to the `Obstacle` and the `Obstacle` also has a reference back to the `GameObject` - there's no way to determine what references an instance of `Obstacle`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response. I will have to find another solution